# Update Session Value

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables, session-state

I have creating an session at the time of login, in that Session I have put the user object.

```
public sealed class MyContext
{

    [ThreadStatic]
    private static MyContext staticContext = null;
    public HttpContext Context
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current;
        }
    }


    private MyContext()
    {

    }

    public static MyContext Current
    {
        get
        {
            MyContext myContext = null;
            HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
            if (context != null)
            {

                //it in the Items collection (a per request store)
                if (context.Items.Contains("CONTEXT_KEY"))
                    myContext = context.Items["CONTEXT_KEY"] as MyContext;
                else
                {
                    myContext = new MyContext();
                    myContext.Context.Items["CONTEXT_KEY"] = myContext;
                }
            }
            else if (staticContext != null)
            {
                myContext = staticContext;
            }
            else
            {
                //create a new instance of static context as there is no web request
                staticContext = new MyContext();
                myContext = staticContext;
            }
            return myContext;
        }
    }

    public MyUser User
    {
        get
        {
            MyUser user = null;
            if (Current.Context.Session["LoggedInUser"] != null)
                user = (MyUser)Current.Context.Session["LoggedInUser"];
            else
            {
                user = UserDetail.GetUser(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
                if (user == null)
                {
                    //if there is no userID, create anonymous user
                    user = new MyUser();
                    user.IsAnonymous = true;
                    user.UserID = 0;
                }
                //cache in session
                Current.Context.Session["User"] = user;
            }
            return user;
        }
        set
        {
            Current.Context.Session["User"] = value;
        }
    }


}//end class
```

Now I am using this Context in whole application, I am facing problem in one case if user is login and same time admin Deactivate that user, I can't stop the user activity, this is because user's information is in session.
So please suggest me how to update that particular user's information when admin deactivate that user.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your question you could only create an event! When the admin deactivate a user it could generate an event, and your user session would immediately respond to it.
It is only an idea, I am not used to session!

Comment: @Other: I am think the same but did not have any Idea how to update particular user's information.

Answer (score 0):

If I was in that situation. I would have to refactor some code to occasinally check the backend to re-authenticate the user - so that if the login was deactived it would get caught.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to check each incoming page request to see if the user has been deactivated and if so reset the session variables. For example you could write a base class that inherits the Page class and overrides Page_Load. The base class Page_Load could perform the check. For all pages that need to check (probably all pages) they should simply inherit the Base class instead of Page class.